# Shiny data frame filtering

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, reactive

I am trying to filter the mitigations data frame by risk id. When a user selects records from risk_list the 2nd table mitigations will automatically filter on risk_id to only those records with a matching claim id in risk_list.

```
library(shiny)
library(editData)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h2("Risk List"),
  textInput("risk_list","Enter data name",value="risk_list"),
  editableDTUI("risk_list"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test"),

  h2("Mitigations"),
  textInput("mitigations","Enter data name",value="mitigations"),
  editableDTUI("mitigations"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test2"),

  h2("Unmitigated"),
  textInput("unmitigated","Enter data name",value="unmitigated"),
  editableDTUI("unmitigated"),
  verbatimTextOutput("test3")


  )
server <- function(input, output) {


  data=reactive({
    myget(input$risk_list)
  })


  data2=reactive({
    myget(input$mitigations)
    })

  data3=reactive({
    myget(input$unmitigated)
  })


   df=callModule(editableDT,"risk_list",data=reactive(data()))
   output$test=renderPrint({
   str(df())
     })

   df2=callModule(editableDT,"mitigations",data=data2)
   output$test2=renderPrint({
   str(df2())
    })

   df3=callModule(editableDT,"unmitigated",data=data3)
   output$test3=renderPrint({
   str(df3())
   })


  }
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have exhauseted my attempts and I am hoping that someone can help.